# Type 'Api.Controllers.' does not have a default constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, asp.net-web-api

I have an controller that use dependency injection:

```
   public FeedController(IFeedProcessor feedProcessor)
        {
            _feedProcessor = feedProcessor;
        }
```

This my config code:

```
public static void Config()
    {

        ObjectFactory.Initialize(x => x.Scan(scan =>
            {
                x.For<IFeedProcessor>().Use<FeedProcessor>();
            }));
    }
```

My FeedProcessor class has parameter constructor:

```
 public FeedProcessor(IFeedParserFactory ifeedParserFactory)
        {
            _ifeedParserFactory = ifeedParserFactory;
        }
```

This StructureMapControllerFactory 
:

```
    public class StructureMapControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
    {
        protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
        {
            if (controllerType == null)
                if (requestContext.HttpContext.Request.Url != null)
                    throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Page not found: {0}", requestContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));
            return ObjectFactory.GetInstance(controllerType) as Controller;
        }
    }
```

and i get this error:
Type 'Api.Controllers.FeedController' does not have a default constructor
How can i config structure map for this scenario?

Comment: Please post your code where do you set your dependency resolver!

Comment: Is your IFeedParserFactory (the dependency of the FeedController) registered correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WebApi does not use the `DefaultControlFactory` to create instances of Api controllers.  Instead, it uses `DefaultHttpControllerSelector`.  However, unless you have a specific reason to create a controller factory, I would instead use the Dependency Resolver system built into MVC.

http://buchanan1966.tumblr.com/post/2192279804/mvc3-using-dependencyresolver-with-structuremap

http://marisks.net/2012/08/19/configuring-structuremap-in-aspnet-webapi/

Answer (score 0):

I ended up getting this exception because I had cyclical dependency in a couple classes in my app.